# App with multiple categories in Django CMS

Tags: django, django-cms

we are trying to migrate a project written with Drupal to Django CMS and we faced a problem with article module. Our site is divided in sections and we have a news module installed in every section with a category, url structure is looking like this:

```
/section1
    /news-category1
/section2
    /news-category2
/etc..
```

This is the same news module, just split in categories (some news articles can pop up in multiple sections, in this case one section is chosen as base to form unique article URL). The only one method I found makes this structure:

```
/news
    /caregory1
    /category2
/etc...
```

Which is not good for us as we would prefer to keep the current URL structure for SEO purposes. Is there a correct way to implement this in Django CMS beside creating each section as a module and plugging in in to a page? Or can I some-how install the same module to multiple pages and pass the section information to it?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this I found myself would be to plug-in the same module to every page it will be on and then have it to parse the path of the page to figure out it's category. Not super-officiant but might work. Not sure if there is any other way.